# How to read file headers in Python similar to C?

Tags: python, file-io, header

I am new to Python. I am a C programmer by profession. I have file, whose header has some specific data, that I need to extract. For example, Byte 0-5 has a magic, Byte 6-8 has offset etc.

In C (An Example) :

```
struct {  
   int32_t payload_offset,  
   int32_t len,  
   char *magic,  
   int32_t type  
   int32_t header_size  
} file_hdr;
```

Then in my function, I do the following:

```
file_hdr *hdr;
ptr = &hdr;
fd = open(path_to_file, "r");
num_read =  read(fd, ptr, bytes).
```

Then I can access header data like this ptr->type, ptr->magic etc.

How do I achieve similar effect in Python? Since Python variables do not have types, what is the best way to access file header data?

I need to use the header data for making some decisions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use the python `struct` module, docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).
Another option, if you need something more powerful, is to use the awesome [construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/) library that can do the above and much more.

Comment: The link to construct is dead.  The new one appears to be [here](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: The Construct library is pretty great, although the documentation will sometimes be confusing if you don't know the concepts they're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically done using the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module in Python. It allows you to extract values from packed binary representations, driven by format-specification strings that you provide.

You would load the data in using binary I/O into a string, then unpack it using struct.unpack().